# Kitten going potty next to litter box

Tags: cats, training, toilet-training, multi-pet-families

My kitten had been pooping in a corner, so I put a litter box in that corner. It's a large box for his size with low walls and is kept clean. He walks into the box, scratches around, and then exits and goes potty right next to the box. Why is he doing this and how can I prevent him from doing this?

Comment: Just to add, I have one other cat and three litter boxes

Comment: Potty training for kittens. Catch in the act, put in the box. Clean old spot (really well) so no smell remains.

Comment: How old is your cat? Is he neutered or declawed? Have you taken him to the vet to check for health issues? Is he going poop or pee or both outside the box?

Comment: He is neither neutered or declawed, but I plan on neutering  him soon. He is only going pee outside of his box

Comment: how old is he? Have you taken him to the vet to check for health issues?

Answer (score 2):

Hm.... sounds like a territorial issue. with that many litter boxes, there may be a problem with the two cats and three litter boxes. Try putting a box away and moving one somewhere else.

Comment: Rule of thumb for litter boxes is number of cats plus one, so two cats with 3 boxes is correct.  See related [Why should there be one more litter box than the total number of cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/996)

Comment: What gender is the other cat? Males and females have issues with having their catboxes in the same area with the other gender.