# Why is my kitten pooping and peeing everywhere?

Tags: cats

Our kitten uses the cat litter often, but she still goes other places as well. She pees or poops on our bed while we are sleeping in it. We have seen her do it on our 3 year old's bed when he is sleeping. She is just going everywhere, and we don't know why.

We have 2 other cats and they do not do this. They use the cat litter all the time. Sometimes we don't notice that she has peed somewhere for a few hours, resulting in a very bad smell. I am pregnant and can't take the smell anymore.

I have tried washing everything twice a day. I tried just throwing things away and buying new ones, but she will still go on that.

How can we solve this problem quickly?

Comment: how old is the kitten.

Comment: Without more information from you, my first guesses are: 1) There are too few litter boxes in the house for all your cats and/or 2) The litter box(es) are not cleaned often enough. Please read more in "[How many litter boxes should you have?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24063/12501)" and "[Why should there be one more litter box than the total number of cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/996/12501)"

Comment: @Elmy this is probably correct and to add to this it is best to put the litter boxes in different areas of the house.

Comment: There are numerous questions on failing to use the litterbox. If this is a recent development, it's probably either a medical issue, or some change happened to make the cat not like the box. However, since it's a kitten, I suspect it may have never learned to use the box properly in the first place. Suggest keep it out of bedroom at minimum until resolved due to the risk of toxoplasmosis to pregnant women.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you have two other cats makes me think the kitten has problems feeling at home in your house. Cats need to be able to smell their own scent to see the house as their home.

I have a feeling the kitten is trying to mark the area as its own but is overwhelmed by the scent of the other two cats. The only way the kitten knows how to mark the area is to use the strongest smell it can.

You need to give the kitten its own stuff like a cat tree, toys, food bowl and, litterbox, and you need to be sure the kitten uses this first so it can claim this as "*mine only mine*".

The litter box needs to be placed away from the other cats' litter box(es). It's best if you can place this in a separate room where the other cats do not go or at least seldom go. You need to put the kitten's cat tree in the same room so it can put its scent on it.

If you have not done this yet, take the kitten to the vet for a checkup, vaccines and spay/neuter. It is best if you get a new carrier for the kitten and put a towel inside. You can put this towel in/on the new cat tree when you return from the vet to add this scent to the cat tree or put it on the kitten's bed.

After the kitten has started to adjust living in your house, you can move its stuff to where you want it to be.